# When I run my ASP.NET Web API always is hosted on a random port, how to avoid that?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

So I have a solution  with a Web Api, I also added Container Orchestation Support, so it's all dockerized.

This is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  acmeapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}acmeapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AcmeAPI/Dockerfile

  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - "14330:1433"
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Abc*123!
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    volumes:
      - sqlserver-data:/var/opt/mssql

volumes:
  sqlserver-data:
```

this is my Program.ccs file:

```
using DataAccessLayer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//For Entity Framework
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContextCore>();

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

#region

//Inyeccion de dependencias


//DALs


// BLs


#endregion

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

UpdateDatabase();

app.Run();


void UpdateDatabase()
{
    using (var context = new DataAccessLayer.DBContextCore())
    {
        context?.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

Every time I run the applications, it hosts in a random port, and I don't want that, I want to set a specific port so it always runs there.

So far I have tried adding this in docker-compose.yml (in the acmeapi service)

```
 ports:
 - "14331: 14331"
```

adding this line in the Program.cs

```
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:14331");
```

but it doesn't work

I'm using NET 7.0 and Visual Studio 2022

Comment: I didn't parse the answer from the page, but I'm sure it is here somewhere: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you. Thanks~

Comment: i made it work by modifying only the docker-compose. i was not setting the right port on the right side (the internal api port was 433). Anyways thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:14331");
```

to

```
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://*:14331");
```

And it should be work. If not, we can try to change the `.yml` file.

#### UPDATE

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}acmeapi
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: AcmeAPI/Dockerfile
ports:
  - "14331:443"
```

Comment: Made it work, was using wrong port in yml file.

 `
ports:
  - "14331:443"
`
That was the right thing to do

Comment: Hi @Alexis252 , thanks for your sharing, I will modify the answer, so that it can help other community users who face the same issue.